# JavaScript if input starts with 'x'

Tags: javascript, forms

I built a JavaScript application with an input field, I want to check if the input is X write Y, but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" style="color:#cccccc;background-color:#000000" name="inputFeld" size="90" onchange="input()" autofocus>
```

This is the HTMl an this the JavaScript:

```
function input() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputField");
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    if (inp.substring(1) == "x") {
        out.innerHTML = ".....";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `substring` on an HTML Element? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: *but it doesn't work* - that helps no one. *What* doesn't work? How does it not work?

Comment: Use your browser console... the error thrown there is a big clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string[n]` to get character at n-th position (starts from zero).
Also, `onchange` only triggered when you out-focus the input, you may want to use `oninput` instead that triggered everytime there is an input to the input element.

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" style="color:#cccccc;background-color:#000000" name="inputFeld" size="90" onchange="input()" autofocus>
<p id="output"></p>
```

```js
function input() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    if (input[0] == "x") {
        output.innerText = "the input starts with x";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`substring(1)` it remove the first value. so try `substring(0,1)` and also apply the `value` in input element field. without `value` is not gettiing the input string .

```js
function input() {
    var inp = document.getElementById("inputField").value;//value is important
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    if (inp.substring(0,1) == "x") {
        console.log('strat with x')
    }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" style="color:#cccccc;background-color:#000000" name="inputFeld" size="90" onchange="input()" autofocus>
```

Comment: Should mention the important part of using the element `value` property

Comment: I'd rather suggest `.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/b6th45kd/)

If you're using jQuery here's your solution

```
<input type="text" id="myinput"><br>
<div class="out"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('input', '#myinput', function() {
  if ($("#myinput").val().substring(0, 1) == "x") {
    $(".out").empty().append('begins with x');
  } else {
    $(".out").empty();
  }
});
</script>
```

If you're using javascript here's your solution

```
<input type="text" id="myjarinput" onkeyup="run()"><br>
<div id="outjar"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var run = function() {
  var injar = document.getElementById("myjarinput").value;
  var outjar = document.getElementById("outjar");
  if (injar.charAt(0) == "x") {
    outjar.innerHTML = 'begins with  x';
  } else {
    outjar.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
</script>
```

Note you can use .substring(0,1) in place of .charAt(0) both are well supported cross browser, however [0] is not advisable, due to browser support.

with .substring(0,1) you can easily use .substring(0,2) to get second character and so on.